# How to suppress error if an argument is missing in a function call?

Tags: php

I made a function like this (no need to write the whole function here) :

```
public function selectNode($from, $attributes = null, $childs = null)
```

and, of course, if I call it this way :

```
$node->selectNode();
```

The argument `$from` isn't initialized and then you got a warning error.
I know you can suppress the error doing `@$node->selectNode();` or something like that thanks to `@`.

But, I want to handle it myself. **How can I do that** if that's possible?

The only way I found is to initialize it like this `public function selectNode($from = null, $attributes = null, $childs = null)` but that doesn't make it clear ($from is not an option as the others).

(And, of course, this function, here, is just an example. It could be extended to other functions)

Comment: What do mean by "handle it myself"? You should look at exceptions.

Comment: As I said in the answer below, exceptions and try/catch seems like a good start. But still, the default PHP Warning is still displaying (it's normal, it's like a parse error).

Comment: Ok, with the Try/Catch from Thariama's advice, I added `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));` in my class's constructor and that answered the question even if it's not good (on a developer's point of view) not to let the warning displayed !

Comment: Most stupid thing you can do ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [try-catch block](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) handling the error yourself.

```
try {
  $node->selectNode();
}
catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e; // do whatever you like here with error info $e, if you leave the parenthesis empty here nothing is done and the error message is suppressed
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still displays the warning message, plus another one `exception 'Exception' with message 'uhoh, no "where" statement?'`. But, now, it stops the function when it finds an exception (I added `if (!$from) {throw new Exception('uhoh, no "where" statement?');}` in my function.

Answer (score 5):

How come you can miss a required parameter? It is not a file or an outside variable! You will get this error just by trying to call this script. It is like parse error. What to handle here? 
It's development phase error. It just needs to be corrected, not handled.

Anyway, you are doing it wrong.

**Never add intentional errors to your code.**

Language's error reporting mechanism is for handling *unexpected* errors, not intentional ones.
If you expect an error here - handle it yourself. Don't make PHP to raise error
So, make it `$from = null,`, yes. And then handle this null whatever you want.

Comment: I don't want to put intentional error in my code. I just wanted to suppress the default PHP error and handling this case (someone calling it with no parameters, someone dumb enough...) myself (showing another message, stopping the function and call another one, I still don't know yet). The Try/Catch seems to be a nice start, but still have the `Warning`

Comment: @Chouchenos what's wrong with this Warning? Just leave it as is.

Answer (score 4):

Surely if the $from parameter is not required you **should** assign it a default variable so it's optional and then do checking based on this.

It would probably be most elegant to just check if $from **isset** in the code before you reference it and supply it with null as default in the parameters, isset will return **false** from a null value.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you've got display_errors set to on in php.ini and now these warnings are popping up on your screen and you don't want to **see** them popping up anymore? If that's the case, then change your php.ini :

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /path/to/php-error.log
```

Errors will then be logged to the file you specified in error_log, and won't show up on your screen anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to my php.ini

Comment: @Chouchenos - But you do have access to ini_set(), don't you?

Comment: @Chouchenos: Don't tell me you've got a production server configured with display_errors=On... If so, I would have a word with the admin that set it up like that, and have him change it immediately.

Comment: @wimvds : Actually, yes, it's configured like this u_u. That's the point of my question. It's a multi-member server... even if it's not free, it's still not so much configurable :(

Comment: @GZipp : Actually, I just tried, and yes ! Thanks, I changed my ini_set to : `ini_set("display_errors", "off");ini_set("log_errors", "on");ini_set('error_log', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/nodeError.log');` and works fluently :)

Comment: @Chouchenos - Good job! :) But you should put the log in a directory where it won't be viewable by site visitors (or use .htaccess to deny access).

Comment: Right, I should do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the following (or one of its variants)?

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
```